# Как работает метод "User.locate()" в aiogram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот

Разъясните, пожалуйста, работу метода User.locate() в aiogram. Ни в одной документации нет объяснения как он работает и для чего нужен. Говорят, что возвращает местоположение пользователя, но у меня вернул ошибку.